# Html, Javascript, Create a textarea that automatically limits the amount of rows (NOT just newlines)

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I want to create a textarea in html that limits the amount of lines it can contains, for example, let's say it can contain 6 lines. However, not just newlines (/r/n, after a user presses enter) but also when a newline is automatically started. For example, this paragraph contains 4 lines, but I haven't pressed the enter key any time at all. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you not set the font size and textarea height with css?

Comment: I don't think this is possible because the text from the text box is just a string. The rendering of the number of lines the text in the text box takes up is not a property as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way to implement described behaviour while users can define their own fonts and scale pages in the web-browsers. Your question take 3 lines for me, for example.